# Put bigger RAM stick size than whats said in MB manual

Tags: windows-7, memory, motherboard

I am trying to boost a bit an old computer, Ive looked the motherboard manual and they say that "You may install 256 MB, 512 MB, and 1 GB unbuffered non-ECC DDR2 DIMM's into the DIMM sockets."It also says that it "support up to 4GB of unbuffered non-ECC 667/533Mhz DDR2 DIMMs". There is 4 memory slot, and at the moment 3 are being used (2x512MB + 1 x 1GB stick). So I have 3 questions. First, could I use a DIMM stick that is more than 1GB? And then, can I use DIMM stick that are faster than 667/533Mhz(ex:800Mhz or more) and last, could I put a total of RAM of more than 4GB or not? The motherboard is an Asus P5LD2-VM LGA-775 for information purpose.

Thank you!

Comment: Generally, when a motherboard manufacturer state there's a limitation, then that's the only sizes that they've tested.  Perhaps a 2GB or larger stick will work, but the manufacturer didn't test for it.

Comment: So could I risk buying a 2GB stick or I should just go with 1GB

Comment: Could use a 2 GB+ module, I suppose you could, but you will be hard pressed to find anything larger than a 1 GB DDR2 module

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, but will it work? Who knows, doubtful but you can try.
2. Sometimes you can use faster memory but the bios will clock it down to match the slowest ram stick installed.
3. Doubtful unless there is a motherboard bios update that allows more memory.